# Using elementary ring theory to show that $\langle xy^3, x^2y^2, x^3y\rangle$ cannot be generated by 2 elements over $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to show that the ideal $\langle xy^3, x^2y^2, x^3y\rangle$ in $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ cannot be generated by 2 elements.

I found a proof online but it was quite involved. This question is at the end of an introductory text on rings. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The quotient I/J of that ideal by the ideal J generated by all monomials of degree 5 has dimension 3. Show that if we had two polynomials f and g which generate I, the images of f and g in I/J would generate the quotient I/J. That is absurd.

Comment: Your $J$ is not a subset of $I$ since $x^5\notin I$. Take $J=\left<x^4y,x^3y^2,x^2y^3,xy^4\right>$ instead.

Comment: Actually I was thinking about the dimension of (I+J)/J!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez For $I = \langle xy^3, x^2y^2, x^3y\rangle$ and $J=\left<x^4y,x^3y^2,x^2y^3,xy^4\right>$, I don't see how to show that $I/J$ has dimension 3. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Did you read my comment above?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes. I thought from the first comment the argument would work with $I$ and $J$ as I wrote above. Anyhow, In your solution $J = \langle x^5, x^4y, x^3y^2, x^2y^3, xy^4, y^5\rangle$. With this $J$, I don't see how to show that $(I+J)/J$ has dimension 3 either. Thank you for the help :-)

Comment: Well, have you found a basis of that quotient? Or, for a simpler question, do you know a basis of the ideal J as a vector space?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'm confused. Wouldn't finding a basis of $J$ (and proving that it is indeed a basis) be even more difficult then finding a basis for $I$?

Comment: Well, it is actually very easy to do. Just do it.

Comment: @mathUser, do you know a convenient basis for the whole ring of polynomials?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Over what ring? A basis over $\mathbb{C}$ will not be a basis of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Comment: A basis over the field. Remember we are trying to compute the dimension of the quotient (I+J)/J as a vector space. We could not care less that the basis will not be a basis over C[x,y]!

Comment: (No non-principal ideal of a polynomial ring is free as a module over the ring, by the way, and J and I and their sums are not principal!)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry. I meant that if we look at $I+J/J$ as a vector space, then what is it's underlying field? $\mathbb{C}$? I'm quite loss with your solution but I appreciate your trying to help :-)

Comment: $\mathbb C$, of course.